# Speed up CSS crossfade animation

Tags: html, css

I have a method to crossfade images, but it's way too slow. I like the time it takes to transition...but the transition itself is way too slow and needs sped up. I've tried a number of things to no avail and some help and a little explanation would be greatly appreciated. Also note I like this method due to the browser support. Thanks in advance!

```
#crossfade > img {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: none;
    max-height: none;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 75s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 75s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 75s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 75s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 75s linear infinite 0s;
}

#crossfade > img:nth-child(2)  {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 15s;
    -o-animation-delay: 15s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 15s;
    animation-delay: 15s;s
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s;
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 45s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 45s;
    -o-animation-delay: 45s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 45s;
    animation-delay: 45s;
}
#crossfade > img:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 60s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 60s;
    -o-animation-delay: 60s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 60s;
    animation-delay: 60s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; }
    5% { opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; }
    5% { opacity: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: linear; }
    5% { opacity: 1;
    -o-animation-timing-function: linear; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear; }
    5% { opacity: 1;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: linear; }
    5% { opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: linear; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

Fiddle Included
https://jsfiddle.net/joelssk/eoq5q8ne/

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'm having a hard time understanding the shorthand of whats going on here.

Comment: See, that's almost what I thought..The transition itself doesn't take 75 seconds, I thought that was shorthand for the duration..and when I change it - it tries to transition really fast but keeps the image the same....from what I understand of it - the 75s comes from the last img (img:nth-child(5)) + the duration between..

Comment: @AlessioCantarella By your response I don't believe you understand exactly what's going on here either.